# can i set LatLngObject in PlacePicker.IntentBuilder to see that place in map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, gmsplacepicker

My code is this. it is working fine.
How can i set **Latitude** and **Longitude** in `PlacePicker.IntentBuilder` so that i can see the location in map

```
   try {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();                
            Intent intent = builder.build(MainActivity.this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE) {
            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
            Khet_Location = address.toString();
            Place_Name = name + "," + address;
            String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
            if (attributions == null) {
                attributions = "";
            }
            current_location_id.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            current_location_id.setText(Place_Name);
            Double latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            Double longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
            Address_lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
            Address_long = String.valueOf(longitude);
        }else
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You means focus all place pickers, i don't understand very well you question...

but check [this...](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlacePicker.IntentBuilder)

setLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds latLngBounds)

example

```
for i to n{
   array coords
   add in LatLngBounds
}
placepicker.setLatLngBounds(latLngBounds)
```